# Sass with Web Workbench delay to save the .scss file so writind the .css

Tags: sass

i am newly implementing sass in my project, the steps i have played are
-installed ruby
executed the following commands
-gem install compass
-compass watch
-compass compile
finally css file is overwriting by sass, but with a delay of time to save the sass file.
i am fully stuck with it. Anyone please suggest any idea.